# Problem with Pantum 3300DW printer installation in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing

I have installed a Pantum 3300DW printer on my desktop via USB. The driver loaded fine. The driver was downloaded off the Pantum website. There is an installer_x86-64 file as well as a pantum_1.1.94_amd64.deb fileThe printer is recognized when I enter lsusb in terminal. When I try to print nothing happens. I checked the print queue which shows the number of jobs and it says either "processing" or "held". I tried releasing to no effect. According to Pantum 20.04 is supported. I spent an entire day trying to get it to work. I can print to the printer wirelessly from my Android phone. I tried a windows laptop via USB and it also worked. Any solutions or help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the driver loaded fine". Did you install proprietary drivers from the vendor? if so, which one and from where?

Comment: Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.
  
You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab.
  
From the command line,
`lpstat -t`
  
will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: @ChanganAuto the driver was downloaded off the Pantum website. There is an installer_x86-64 file as well as a pantum_1.1.94_amd64.deb file. Ubuntu recognizes the printer as well.

Comment: @waltinator I did try local:host631. I cannot remember what message came up. Will try again as soon as I get home from work. Will post results here.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @waltinator when I run lpstat from the command line I get the following:

Comment: scheduler is running
system default destination: Pantum_-Printer
device for Pantum-P3300DW: ipp://Pantum%20P3300DW%20Series%202BEB3A%20(USB)._ipp._tcp.local/
device for Pantum_-Printer: ipp://Pantum%20P3300DW%20Series%202BEB3A%20(USB)._ipp._tcp.local/
Pantum-P3300DW accepting requests since Sun 21 Aug 2022 18:48:18
Pantum_-Printer accepting requests since Tue 23 Aug 2022 19:13:31

Comment: printer Pantum-P3300DW is idle.  enabled since Sun 21 Aug 2022 18:48:18
printer Pantum_-Printer now printing Pantum_-Printer-179.  enabled since Tue 23 Aug 2022 19:13:31
 Unable to get printer status.
Pantum_-Printer-179     moki             50176   Tue 23 Aug 2022 19:13:31

Comment: OK finally got it to work. In settings under printers 5 printers appear. CUPS-BRF_Printer, Pantum_IPP_printer_USB_, Pantum_P3300DW_Series, Pantum_P3300DW_Series_2BEB3A and Pantum_P300DW_Series_moki_H310M_DS2.

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work from here. I eventually got into localhost:631 and selected a Pantum 3300DW printer and driver from there and it now works. Under printer settings in Ubuntu the printer is now listed as Pantum_P3300DW_Series and the model as Pantum P3300DN Series PS. I tried deleting the other printers (except for CUPS), but they keep re-appearing.

Comment: What is the name of the driver you selected?

Comment: @brian_p the driver which I selected and is currently working is Pantum_P3300DW_Series

Answer (score 0):

- The Pantum 3300DW  does not exist. The Pantum P3300DW does. The typo didn't help.
- The Pantum P3300DW is a quite recently marketed printer that is capable of driverless printing. Vendor drivers are not required. Why lead a user down the latter path? The present Ubuntu is geared up for driverless printing. In the future it is the only printing that will be done by the system.
- Nobody seems bothered about which Ubuntu is being used. From the device URI I reckon it is 22.o4. @Mokiki will correct me should I be wrong.
- Execute

```
lpadmin -p P3300 -v "ipp://Pantum%20P3300DW%20Series%202BEB3A%20(USB)._ipp._tcp.local/" -E -m everywhere
```

- Test  printing with

```
lp -d P3300 /etc/nsswitch.conf
```